# Request using form data http client symfony

Tags: symfony, multipartform-data

My Class

```
private function request(string $url, string $method, array $options = [],string $token):    ResponseInterface
{
$endpoint = $_ENV['FILE_ENDPOINT'];

        $formData = new FormDataPart($options);
    
        $header = $formData->getPreparedHeaders();
        $header->addTextHeader('Authorization', "Bearer $token");
    
        return $this->httpClient->request(
            $method,
            $endpoint . $url,
            [
                'headers' => $header->toArray(),
                'body' => $formData->bodyToIterable(),
            ]
        );
    }     `
```

`$options`

[image]

`The error I get`

[image]

Tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to solve this problem or another solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an example on how it could work. Adapt your code using this:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Part\TextPart;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Multipart\MultipartStream;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Multipart\FormDataPart;

private function request(string $url, string $method, array $options = [], string $token): ResponseInterface
{
    $endpoint        = $_ENV['FILE_ENDPOINT'];
    $multipartStream = new MultipartStream();

    foreach ($options as $name => $value) {
        $multipartStream->addPart(new TextPart($value, 'form-data', ['name' => $name]));
    }

    $fileContents = 'Contenu du fichier'; // Remplacez cela par le contenu réel du fichier
    $formData = new FormDataPart($fileContents);
    $formData->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'form-data; name="file"; filename="filename.txt"');
    $multipartStream->addPart($formData);

    $headers = [
        'Authorization' => "Bearer $token",
    ];

    return $this->httpClient->request(
        $method,
        $endpoint . $url,
        [
            'headers' => $headers,
            'body' => $multipartStream->toIterable(),
        ]
    );
}
```

Comment: My version of symfony is 5.4 and I don't have the Symfony\Component\Mime\Multipart\MultipartStream component